# How to make Safari on my Mac sort bookmarks like Safari on my iPhone (by date added)?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, safari, bookmarks

For the longest time, I thought my bookmarks weren't synching (despite having the iCloud Safari synch turned on on both devices and being logged into the same Apple ID), but I just discovered that they're just sorted differently.  I use bookmark folders quite a bit and I frequently add bookmarks to those folders.  And whenever I've added one from my phone, I typically navigate to the bottom of that folder on my Mac, expecting to see it there, but it never is.

I didn't explicitly select a sort order on either device, but the sort order appears to be:

- Safari on iOS 15.6.1 - sorted by date added (newest at the bottom)
- Safari 16.0 on macOS 12.6 - random (definitely not name and definitely not URL)

And on the Mac, the only sort options I can find are by name or by URL:

[image]

Is it not possible to have them both sorted the way the iPhone default sorts them (by date added)?  Does anyone else see a default order of date-added on the mac?  (I suppose it's possible that if I drop a new bookmark on the mac, it will be added at the bottom of the items in that folder, but I usually add bookmarks from my phone, so I haven't tested what that would do.

Comment: In Safari use the History

It shows the web sites by date, unfortunately not the bookmarks